# Google Font License

Tags: fonts

I designed a new Website and I need fonts for this. So I have found Google Fonts. But I don't know in which form I can use these. Do I have to give credits or any other things for that?

Comment: A great question, but not programming related, so you would have better luck somewhere else! However: https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#Any_Page_OK

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Google Fonts are free and open-source, so you can use them freely without any further references to Google Fonts or Google.

On the Google Fonts site they state:

> All of the fonts are Open Source. This means that you are free to share your favorites with friends and colleagues. You can even customize them for your own use, or collaborate with the original designer to improve them. And you can use them in every way you want, privately or commercially — in print, on your computer, or in your websites.

[https://www.google.com/fonts#AboutPlace:about](https://www.google.com/fonts#AboutPlace%3aabout)